# Voiceflow connect to Whatsapp

Tags: whatsapp, whatsapi, whatsapp-cloud-api

I'm confused about connecting Voiceflow to Whatsapp. There are some YouTube tutorials on how to do it via MannyChats and other connectors, but how will I be charged? do I need to only pay for MannyChats or will I be charged by Meta in my Meta business account (I read they charge per conversation)?

I want to estimate the cost. will I only need to pay for ManyChats and Voiceflow subscriptions or do I also need to pay for WhatsaAppa API per conversation.

Is there any free or cheap way to connect the voiceflow with Whatsapp?